# jquery datatable border issue

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

How to show the border for empty cells ? There some columns are blank and no values , so those columns are not displaying the border and its blank.Please see the below screen shot and advise.

One more is there are two lines of border , How to make it one of border ?

**HTML**

```
<table border="1"  id="products1" style="width:750px" >   
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>End Date</th>
                <th>Modify Date</th>
                <th>Comments</th>
                <th>By Who</th>
               </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS**

```
oTable = $("#products1").dataTable({
       "aaData": newarray, 
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bDeferRender": true,
       "bFilter": true,
       "bRetrieve": true,
       "bPaginate": true,
       "bJQueryUI": true,
       "iDisplayLength": 5,

       "sPaginationType": "two_button",
       "sDom": 'T<"clear">frtip',
        "aoColumns": [{"sWidth": "135px","sClass": "center","bSortable": true},{
            "sWidth": "145px","sClass": "center","bSortable": true},{
            "sWidth": "145px","sClass": "center","bSortable": true},{
            "sWidth": "20px","sClass": "center","bSortable": false}

            ],
        "aoColumnDefs": [{ "fnRender": function (o, val) {
            return o.aData[0];
        },
            "sClass": "end date","aTargets": [0]
    }, {
        "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[1];
        },
            "sClass": "modified date","aTargets": [1]
    }, {
    "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[2];
        },
            "sClass": "comments","aTargets": [2]
    },{
    "fnRender": function (o, val) {

            return o.aData[3];
        },
            "sClass": "By who","aTargets": [3]
    }
    ]

});
```

Comment: The problem is in the <tbody> isn't it? So where's its code?

Comment: it looks like you left out the `<td>` when there was no value. Unless you adjust colspan is invalid that way

Comment: show the tbody rows html that create the image display

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example provided is incorrect, the table name in HTML & JS is not matching, also please provide a sample array **"aaData": newarray** for replicating your exact issue.

When I am using my own sample array, it is working fine,

```
oTable = $("#products1").dataTable({
    "aaData": [
        ["2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "", "user1"],
        ["2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "", "user1"],
        ["2013-01-01", "2013-01-01", "hello", "user1"]
     ]
```

For the 2nd question use the CSS Property - **border-collapse: collapse**,

```
<table border="1" id="products1" style="width: 750px;border-collapse: collapse">
```

Comment: Awesome , Its working as expected.After added the `border-collapse: collapse` i'm getting border for empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `<td />` for empty cells. You can't just drop the  tag.

Comment: Are you saying like this ?<td> <th>End Date</th></td>
               <td> <th>Modify Date</th></td>
               <td> <th>Comments</th></td>
               <td> <th>By Who</th></td>

Comment: No. The problem is inside <tbody>, not inside <thead>. see this. http://jsfiddle.net/LS4vN/2/

Answer (score 0):

When inspecting your table css, you will probably find the following

```
table {
    empty-cells: hide;
}
```

Change or override it:

```
table {
    empty-cells: show;
}
```

And voila, all the borders are shown, also for empty cells..